# Arrays with 'named' constructors in JavaScript? (e.g HTMLCollection)

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following two ways of creating the **instance of an object**:

```
function f() { return { k: 'v'} }
var inst1 = f();

function F() { this.k = 'v'; } 
var inst2 = new F();
```

The behavior of inst1 and inst2 is the same, the only difference is that a different constructor is saved to the object:

```
inst1.constructor; // Object()
inst2.constructor; // F()
```

What's the constructor of an array? See:

```
var xs = [];
xs.constructor; // Array()
```

Until this Point I understand the logic. But I bumped into the following:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
typeof tags; // object
tags.constructor; // HTMLCollection()
```

So far it's similar to the inst2 example. But when I console.log with Firebug, I receive something like an Array with a 'named' constructor:

```
console.log(tags); // HTMLCollection[tag1, tag2, ...]
```

The block brackets confuse me, I would have expected curly one here. There must be an explanation to this, anybody knows the answer?

Comment: In _JavaScript Arrays_ are _Objects_ `typeof arr; // "object"`. _HTMLCollections_ and _NodeLists_ are _Array-like Objects_ but not _Arrays_. They are also part of the _DOM_ which means they aren't covered by the _ECMAScript_ spec. You can make any _Object_ look like an _Array_ in the console even if it's unknown to the console by giving it a _length_ and a _splice_ `({length: 0, splice: function () {}}); // []`

Comment: Yes, I know this. Maybe it is a FireBug specific issue. What determines if the properties of a console.logged object appear in block brackets or in curly ones. But maybe there is a JavaScript specific explanation for this..

Comment: Firebug is free to display objects in the console however it likes. It will let you click through to the DOM view, too, but that doesn't really tell you anything about JS.

Comment: @AntonHarald Pre-programmed instance types or any object with a _length_ and _splice_

Comment: When I add a length and a splice prop to the constructor, I again get an 'anonymous' console.log: Object["..", ".."]  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dndxjs4k/ According to the HTMLCollection case, I would expect ArrLikeObj["..", ".."] as a console output in this fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the crux of your question lies in determining how Firebug displays your object. Firebug examines objects you passed to it, and chooses how it will display objects as a string based on what properties they have.

HTMLCollection is "array-like" so it has a length property, and stores its contents in properties named 0, 1, 2, etc. This makes it array-like and Firebug recognizes this, outputting the string representation of your object like it would an array.

In the case of Firebug, if it sees a `length` and a `splice` property, it will treat the object as array-like:

```
var MyArrayLike = function(){
    this[0] = 1;
    this.length = 1;
    this.splice = function(){};
}
```

Firebug output:

```
-> new MyArrayLike();
<- [1]
```

Comment: This is a good hint, but Firebug treats this object as being anonymously created ( var x = new MyArrayLike(); console.log(x); // Object[...], not MyArrayLike[...] as I would expect because the example in my post acts like this: console.log(tags) // HTMLCollection[...] )